# How to install Python Packages in the workplace- Windows

Tags: python-3.x, windows, powershell, pip, pypi

I trying to download a package called cbapi on my HP windows 10 laptop but to no avail.

In my juypter notebook on my localhost, I run the following command:

```
!pip install cbapi
```

I receive this error:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021515688908>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cbapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x00000215156889C8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cbapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021515932D08>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cbapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021515934688>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cbapi/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectTimeoutError(<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021515934EC8>, 'Connection to pypi.org timed out. (connect timeout=15)')': /simple/cbapi/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cbapi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for cbapi
```

I am on my workplaces network and wanted to see if there is a work around to installing packages on my user system. Any ideas or suggestions?

If it helps, anaconda is running on my local disk and not my system folder.

Edit--------------

Now I tried:

```
!pip install cbapi-1.6.2.tar.gz --no-index
```

To try to download it  manually but got the following error:

```
Processing c:\users\me\cbapi-1.6.2.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: requests in c:\users\me\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from cbapi==1.6.2) (2.22.0)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement attrdict (from cbapi==1.6.2) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for attrdict (from cbapi==1.6.2)
```

Comment: If pypi is blocked, you can't install it from it. Or you get a permission to use it, or you can download the package and install it manually.

Comment: If i wanted to install it manually, what code would I use when I install the python gz package from pypi?